Apply feature weights to sklearn model for clf.predict
I have identified a set of feature_weights and passed that paramter to the clf.fit function to generate my model fit using sklearn. I want to apply that model to new data one epoch at a time using clf.predict but I cannot find any documentation or posts about how to incorporate the same array of feature weights to the clf.predict function and those weights do not appear to be stored in the clf file (feature importance values are however).
Is it as simple as just multiplying the feature values by the weights or is there some undocumented option?

It would help to see what you are doing, please add a minimal reproducible example of your issue.
